# Pass content of text_area to link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Within a form I have a `text_area`:

```
= f.text_area :post, class: 'post_text'
```

How can I pass the value of the text area to a `link_to`? The following `link_to` should also get the content of the text area.

```
 = link_to 'Lock Discussion', discussion_path(@blog, @post, post: {state: :lock}), method: :put,  class: 'btn btn-lock'
```

I assume it needs some javascript, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you want this to use a form_for rather than a link. A form will give you the ability to pass parameters to your put action rather than trying to tack them on to your link

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your form has the id main_form and your text area has the class of post_text and your link has the class of link_to and you have a submit button  you can try the following

```
$( "#main_form" ).submit(function(e) {
var content = $('.post_text').val();
$('link_to').setAttribute('href', 'content');
e.preventDefault();
};
```